# Класс возвращает null в другую форму C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Метод класса недоступен, а обходной вариант через функцию возвращает null массиву correlation в вызывающей форме.

Класс создаю в Program.cs, а после в форме 1 создаю глобально  экземпляры, которые успешно передают/принимают значения (.

```
public  class __Correlation
    {
          public double[] Get_array { get; set; }
    }
```

К сути: В другой форме нужно получить значения конкретного экземпляра, поэтому обращаюсь к нему. Если обращаюсь к данным таким образом, то компилятор ругается "Form1.k_X недоступен из за уровня защиты".

```
public void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Form1 f = new Form1();
double[] correlation = f.k_X.Get_array; //вызов метода класса
...
}
```

Сделал функцию в форме 1, которая принимает значения экземпляра, а потом уже возвращает их вызывающей форме и в итоге получаю null.

```
 public double[] correlation_X()//функция которая якобы обходной вариант
        {
            double[] array = k_X.Get_array;
            return array;
        }
```

Куда копать? Может быть это из-за того, что экземпляры объявлены в одной форме, а используются в другой?

Comment: Видимо вы пишете в один экземпляр формы, а читаете из другого.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас тут ошибка:

```
public void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Form1 f = new Form1(); //<-- вот тут
double[] correlation = f.k_X.Get_array; //вызов метода класса
...
}
```

Переделайте класс Form2 следующим образом:

```
class Form2 : Form
{
  Form1 form1 = null;
  public Form2(Form1 form1)
  {
    this.form1 = form1;
  }
  public void somecalc() //пример рабочей функции
  {
    var val = form1.****; //читаем нужные нам public свойства из Form1
    //тут считаем
    form1.* = val2; //пишем нужные нам public свойства в Form1
  }
}
```

Вся суть заключается в передаче "себя" (Form1) в дочернюю форму, чтобы была ссылка на форму для доступа в public свойства.
Соответственно когда в Form1 при каком-то действии вы создаёте Form2, в этот Form2 вы должны передать существующий экземпляр Form1:

```
class Form1 : Form
{
   void CallForm2()
   {
     Form2 form2 = new Form2(this); //this - это существующий экземпляр Form1
     form2.Show();
   }
}
```

Comment: Мне кажется это излишне, автор вопроса не показал где он объявляет `Form1.k_X` - скорее всего, сам `k_X` (экземпляр `Correlation` в `Form1`) объявлен private